# Caching a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a PySpark dataframe `df` with ~10M rows. Also let the columns be `[col_a, col_b]`. Which would be faster:

```
df_test = df.sample(0.1)
for i in range(10):
  df_sample = df_test.select(df.col_a).distinct().take(10)
```

or

```
df_test = df.sample(0.1)
df_test = df_test.cache()
for i in range(10):
  df_sample = df_test.select(df.col_a).distinct().take(10)
```

Would caching `df_test` make sense here?

Comment: why don't you just try it ?

Comment: @Steven: I did and it was slower

Comment: quick way to understand what's happening is to check the process DAGs on spark UI. also, why use `df.col_a` in `df_test.select()` where `df` and `df_test` are different dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't make much difference.
it is just one loop where you can skip cache like below

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...   df_sample = df.sample(0.1).select(df.id).distinct().take(10)
```

Here spark is loading Data once in memory.

If you want to use df_sample further in other operations repeatedly then you can use cache()